# How can unmanaged memory usage be viewed?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, memory-leaks, unmanaged

How can unmanaged memory usage be viewed and monitored within Visual Studio in a c# project? Is there a way to check if allocated memory has been properly deleted later while debugging?

Code:
pv_Memory = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(0x200000);

I am attempting to use the 'Diagnostics Tools' within Visual Studio 2015 and can see memory increasing, though it does not appear to separate out unmanaged objects and memory.

Any tips? Thanks.

Configuration:
1. Visual Studio 2015
2. C# application referencing a 3rd party .NET library, which is a wrapper for an unmanaged library 
3. Windows 7

Comment: Generally native code (e.g. c/c++) has to be compiled with certain flags to enable memory leak detection and generally you don't know if you have a leak until the process exits

Comment: @MickyD how can the leak be checked for at process exit?

Comment: Microsoft CRT does it

Comment: @MickyD: That is not true. You can use ETW Heap allocation tracing which needs no special compiler flags at all.

Comment: @AloisKraus oooh learnt something new today.  I did say _"generally"_ ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you are using AllocHGlobal you are allocating from the unmanaged C/C++ Heap. You can track this with Heap allocation tracing.

```
class Program
{
    private static IntPtr pv_Memory;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            pv_Memory = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(0x200000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

xperf from the Windows Performance Toolkit allows you to attach to an already running process to get heap allocation data.

[image]

You can view the data with WPA. 
A good article is here:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2014/12/02/diagnosing-native-memory-leaks-etw-wpa/

This is quite powerful but it needs some practice.

Answer (score -1):

Use MS inbuilt tool CLRProfiler and Perfmon(Performance monitor).  you can get its documentation on internet see this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39246/NET-Best-Practice-No-Improve-garbage-collector) . check ILDASM(IL Disassembler)  tool too.